# Predicting categories based on a similarity matrix

Tags: regression, clustering, model, matrix, similarities

I am looking for some help in organising some analyses. I will describe what I am trying to do with a fictional example and then talk about some of the things I've thought about already.

**Example**

I have a list of individuals with a binary variable showing whether they are from the UK (1) or not from UK (0).

Each individual has then been asked to describe several videos they have seen in 100 words. Each video is either about the weather or about sports.

From this I calculate how similar their answer is to every other individual for each video based on word occurance. Giving me a similarity matrix for each video with scores between 0 & 1.

I want to know, whether people within the UK describe these videos in a more similar way to those outside, and whether this differs depending on the topic.

**What I've considered**

Effectively, I want to be able to model similarity across matrices. If the hypotheses is true, people in the UK describe the weather more similarly than those outside, then we would expect a cluster of similar scores in the same place across matrices. I was curious if I could take each matrix, and turn it into a long form matrix (one row per pair) with extra variables for weather / sport & whether the first listed pair was from the UK or not. And then performa linear model. The issue with this is that points are not independent any longer, since each pair would occur twice in a difference direction. And alternative would be to put each pair once, and indicate whether the pair are both from the UK, both from outside the UK or one of each.

However, I'm not sure if that is getting at the right hypotheses. So i am hoping to crowd source some alternative approaches that I overlooked or have not heard of!

Comment: The first approach is bad because each value is duplicated in the data. Apart from "independence of observations" this alone can make the data ill-conditioned mathematically for the analysis.